# Asking for a date

Tags: mathematics

Not a date comes to your mind at first, but rather a specific date in time:

> This date's human readable form is written as **dd/mm/yyyy**, 
>   and when converted to a Unix Timestamp (epoch time), it's **ddmmyyyy00**.

- dd is the two-digit day of the month
- mm is the two-digit month month of the year
- yyyy is the four-digit year

Note: a Unix Timestamp represents "the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC" ([Source](http://www.convert-unix-time.com/)).

This site might help: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Find such a date, if it exists. If it doesn't, please prove that it doesn't.

Comment: Should it be migrated to Flirting.SE ?

Comment: I think he's wanting you to find a date that when in the format of dd/mm/yyyy, is equal to the unix timestamp that looks the same + two zeroes at the end.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

> 0705199200 converts to dd/mm/yyyy 07/05/1992 (00:40)

Answer (score 2):

The closest match I have found is

> 07/05/1992

which has a timestamp of

> 705196800

which is only 2400 away from what it should be.

I used a small javascript program for it.

```
  console.log("start");
  var best = 1e9;
  for( var y=1970; y<2069; y++ ){
     for( var m=1; m<=12; m++ ){
        for( var d=1; d<=31; d++ ){
           var utc1 = Date.UTC(y,m-1,d)/1000;
           var utc2 = ((d*100+m)*10000+y)*100;
           var dif = Math.abs(utc1-utc2);
           if( dif<best ){
              best = dif;
              console.log(d+"/"+m+"/"+y+"  "+utc1+"  "+utc2);
           }
        }
     }
  }
  console.log("end");
```

You only have to search until 2069 because by then the first two digits exceed 31, so it can no longer represent a date.

Comment: I did my search the other way round, knowing that the yyyy part can be tuned easily. Because the hours and minutes are irrelevant, you'll see that you can actually get a Unix timestamp that matches with the readable format.